# Why do we use private object with lock statement?

Tags: c#, locking

Why we need `private obj`? or any kind of object? What's purpose of parameter of lock?

```
       private static object obj = new object();
        static void Print() {
            lock (obj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine("End");
            }
        }
```

And how to work this code behind?

Comment: because otherwise code outside your class could release the lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we need `private obj`?

It doesn't actually have to be private, the code would work just as well with a public object. And you can lock on any object.

But it is a best practice to hide the lock object as much as possible, and only make it accessible to the code that actually needs it.  This helps to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: More exact: This way avoids (outside of reflection) any abuse of the lock objects by external objects - which can result in deadlocks.